# Jaccard Index between timestamps in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, similarity

I have UNIX timestamps being converted to strings as well as given time string inputs that I need to get Jaccard index from. Following are stored in 2D arrays as time intervals.

```
unix_converted = [['00:00:00', '00:00:03'], ['00:00:03', '00:00:06'], ['00:00:12', '00:00:15']]
input_timestamps = [['00:00:00', '00:00:03'], ['00:00:03', '00:00:06'], ['00:00:06', '00:00:09']]

def jaccard_index(s1, s2):
    raise NotImplementedError
```

Do I have to convert these intervals to datetime objects or there is a way to be a straightforward? And how to get index itself?

Comment: Please consider explaining what the jaccard index is as well as actually providing an attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: You want to calculate the Jaccard Index over the two lists I'm assuming i.e., the parameters in the function `jaccard_index(s1, s2)` are expecting `unix_converted` and `input_timestamps` eh?

Comment: Please provide an expected output as well

Answer (score 1):

You could exploit Python's native support for sets to calculate your Jaccard Index.

```py
unix_converted = [['00:00:00', '00:00:03'], ['00:00:03', '00:00:06'], ['00:00:12', '00:00:15']]
input_timestamps = [['00:00:00', '00:00:03'], ['00:00:03', '00:00:06'], ['00:00:06', '00:00:09']]

def jaccard_index(s1, s2):
    s1 = set({'-'.join(each) for each in s1})
    s2 = set({'-'.join(each) for each in s2})
    return len(s1.intersection(s2))/len(s1.union(s2))

print(jaccard_index(unix_converted, input_timestamps)) #outputs 0.5
```

Edit: I'm assuming by Jaccard Index you meant Jaccard similarity i.e. **intersection over union** of the given lists.

Comment: Note: this calculation works if timestamps in s1 and s2 have the same invervals.

Answer (score 0):

This code calculates Jaccard similarity in situations where timestamps are not necessarily calculated in the same invervals. `O(len(s1)^2 + len(s2)^2)` time complexity.

```
unix_converted = [(1, 3), (6, 10), (11, 12)]
input_timestamps = [(1, 3), (4, 7)]


def jaccard_index(s1, s2):

    def _set_sum(start1, end1, start2, end2):
        """ returns sum if there is an overlap and None otherwise """
        if start2 <= start1 <= end2:
            return start2, max(end1, end2)
        if start1 <= start2 <= end1:
            return start1, max(end1, end2)
        return None  # separate sets

    def _set_intersection(start1, end1, start2, end2):
        """ returns intersection if there is an overlap and None otherwise """
        if start2 <= start1 <= end2:
            return start1, min(end1, end2)
        if start1 <= start2 <= end1:
            return start2, min(end1, end2)
        return None  # separate sets

    # Calculate A u B
    sum = []
    for x, y in s1 + s2:
        matched_elem = False
        for i, (x2, y2) in enumerate(sum):
            set_sum = _set_sum(x, y, x2, y2)
            if set_sum is not None:
                sum[i] = set_sum
                matched_elem = True
                break
        if not matched_elem:
            sum.append((x, y))

    # join overlapping timestamps
    element_is_joined = [False for _ in sum]
    for i, (x, y) in enumerate(sum):
        if not element_is_joined[i]:
            for j, (x2, y2) in enumerate(sum):
                if element_is_joined[j] or i == j:
                    continue
                set_sum = _set_sum(x, y, x2, y2)
                if set_sum is not None:  # overlap is found
                    sum[j] = set_sum
                    element_is_joined[i] = True
                    break

    sum_ = 0
    for (x, y), is_joined in zip(sum, element_is_joined):
        if not is_joined:
            sum_ += y - x

    if sum_ == 0:
        raise ValueError('Division by zero')

    # calculate A ^ B
    intersection = 0
    for x, y in s1:
        for x2, y2 in s2:
            set_intersection = _set_intersection(x, y, x2, y2)
            if set_intersection is not None:
                intersection += set_intersection[1] - set_intersection[0]

    return intersection / sum_


print(jaccard_index(unix_converted, input_timestamps)) #outputs 0.333333
```